# Alternate to Allowing Insecure Unlock

Tags: go-ethereum, security

Several places say insecure unlock is poor practice.

Yet this module I am learning implements it.

Where can I find a way to Deploy an account without insecure unlock

Here is repository with files I am working with, i.e. deploy.js, etc, https://github.com/ArtieLadie/no_unlock

Here is screenshot from Pluralsight

By the way, I tried doing `sudo geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 --allow-insecure-unlock` (and other variations) for learning sake, but that also doesn't work!

[image]

Comment: How is geth launched? If you want to learn I'd suggest to run ganache https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/. It is a node for testing contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than unlocking an account, signing specific transactions is generally a better and more secure way to handle this. There are multiple ways to do this depending on the library you are using. Below are a few examples:

**web3.js**

With web3.js you can create a raw transaction and then sign the raw transaction with the account's private key and send it to the network:

*Ether Transaction*

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction

*Contract Example*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611117/how-to-authenticate-and-send-contract-method-using-web3-js-1-0

**ethersjs**

*Ether Transaction*

Create a wallet using a private key and a transaction - by defining the . Send the transaction

https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#signing

*Contract Call*

With ethers you can create a contract object and connect it with a wallet object. The wallet object contains an address and a private key - so transactions sent from this connected contract object will be signed by that wallet that had been logged into

see 'Calling a Non-Constant Method' here:
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#connecting-to-existing-contracts